# FB_Init method capability

Tags: twincat

I have a function block for alarm management. To make it more flexible, I try and only add new alarms as new enum members in the alarm ID enumeration. To make it flexible, the alarm message and name should be generated at runtime, preferably when the function block is instantiated. Now, my question is, if I do something like this, in the FB_Init method, is this a viable operation or not? Currently I have around 40 alarms, more might be added. Basically I am asking if the FB_Init method has some timing demands that I must take in consideration.

Current FB_Init method, this works fine on my development PC:

```
 FOR i := 0 TO SIZEOF(_arrAlarms)/SIZEOF(ST_AlarmDefinition) - 1 BY 1 DO
    _arrAlarms[i].Name := TO_STRING(_arrAlarms[i].Id);
    FindAndReplace(pDstString := ADR(_arrAlarms[i].Message),
                   pSrcString := ADR(_arrAlarms[i].Name),
                   nDstSize := SIZEOF(_arrAlarms[i].Message),
                   pDeleteString := ADR(sStringToReplace),
                   pInsertString := ADR(sStringToInser));
END_FOR
```

Each data slice is defined :

```
{attribute 'qualified_only'}
{attribute 'strict'}
{attribute 'to_string'}
TYPE ST_AlarmDefinition :
STRUCT
    Id                  : E_AlarmID;    // Alarm ID
    Name                : T_MaxString;  // Name of the alarm, basically the ID as string
    Message             : T_MaxString;  // Message of the alarm
    Active              : BOOL;         // Active state of the alarm
    LastActivationDate  : STRING;       // Date of last activation
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

My second question is : Could I also use custom defined function form my project inside this FB_Init method? I would like to make the message follow a certain algorithm, that way every message can be constructed from the enum name, the names are all following a strict naming convention.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the [TwinCAT 3 EventLogger](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_eventlogger/5001926923.html?id=6291374471499984104)? Looks like you're trying to reinvent the wheel. `FB_init` is called when you instantiate your function block, re initializing it for a new alarm is possible, but not really how it is normally done. See the Eventlogger, which uses the `Create` and `Raise`. Yes for your second question.

Comment: Hi. I have a custom software as HMI and it uses ads to communicate with the PLC. This seems easier and I am just trying to improve its functionality. New alarms can only be added by the PLC code, when I said i want to make it dynamic I meant that i could add N new identifiers and upload new code. Is Event logger free of charge or pay to play :o ?

Comment: You can set your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you're not using the [TwinCAT 3 EventLogger](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_eventlogger/5001926923.html?id=6291374471499984104)? It is free. It looks like you're trying to reinvent the wheel with your current implementation.

Regarding your first question, `FB_init` is called when you instantiate your function block, re initializing it for a new alarm is possible, but not really how it is normally done. See the Eventlogger, which uses the `Create` and `Raise` methods to do this. Yes for your second question.